# Removing part of a Laravel URL if certain conditions apply

Tags: laravel, url, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have a number of routes on my website that use a custom pagination solution, like `/categories/{category}/page/{page?}`. I currently have each controller set like the following:

```
public function index($category, $page = null) {
    if(!isset($page) || !is_numeric($page) || $page < 1) {
        return redirect()->route('parent', ['category' => $category]);
    }
}
```

This has the desired effect of checking if the provided page number exists, is, indeed, a number, and if it is greater than zero. In the event that any of those conditions are false, it redirects to the parent route, `/categories/{category}`.

The problem is, for each of these solutions, they all require me to write in the name of the parent route to do the redirect. If I want to just cut off the `/page/` and onwards, *but keep any get variables and post variables*, how would I do that?

Comment: I think your best bet is to create another route like `/categories/{category}`.

Comment: @noodles_ftw I've done that, that's the way I'm currently doing it. I'm basically just wondering if there's a way to intercept routes before they are processed, and do the check and modification there, keeping get and post variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to redirect back to the previous page with the inputs, use the following code.

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

In the above case, it will work only if you are coming to the url `/categories/{category}/page/{page?}` from `/categories/{category}`

Comment: Is there any way to get the current URL, remove `/page/whatever` from it, and then redirect to that, with input?

Comment: @Furze `Request::url()` will give you the current url. You can use `preg_replace` to remove `/page/whatever`